# How do I secure an odata service running on windows Azure

Tags: windows, authentication, service, azure, odata

I am hosting odata service on windows azure platform. How do I authenticate client/user within windows azure platform before they can access the odata service?

Thanks,

Comment: I thought this must be common pattern but surprised to see no response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the WCF Data Sevice Team´s blog there is a huge entry splitted in 8 parts where they deatils all about authentication:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/05/10/odata-and-authentication-part-1.aspx